# str_replace with random values?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have the following code:

```
    $embed_url = str_replace('<iframe width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="', '', $embed_url);
    $embed_url = str_replace('"></iframe>', '', $embed_url);
```

What happens is the iframe width and height is not fixed values, so they can be any other numbers.

How can I make this works for any width/height?

Thanks.

Edit: What i am trying to get is the src value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
$embed_url = preg_replace('/<iframe width=".*?" height=".*?" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="/', '', $embed_url);
```

If all you want is to retrieve the value of `src`, you could use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead:

```
if (preg_match('/<iframe.*?src="(.+?)"/ms', $embed_url, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use

```
$embed_url = preg_replace('!<iframe width="[0-9]+?" height="[0-9]+?" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="!','',$embed_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str_replace`, just use the built in value substitution, to wit:

```
$width = '512';
$height = '288';

$iframe = '<iframe width="$width" height="$height" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="$embed_url"></iframe>';
```

HTH.